# MLE of multinomial distribution with missing values

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, missing-data, multinomial-distribution

I am trying to solve a problem and the results I get seem counter-intuitive.

We randomly throw $n$ balls into an area partitioned into 3 bins $b_1,b_2,b_3$. The size of each bins is proportional to the probability the ball will fall in it. Let's call these probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3$. This can be described by a multinomial distribution.

Now let's say I throw 12 balls, and I know how many landed in each bin ($x_1=3,x_2=6,x_3=3$).

I would like to estimate the size of the bin from the observations. For this I use Maximum Likelihood. It can be shown that the MLE will be $p_1=3/12,p_2=6/12,p_3=3/12$. This is pretty intuitive.

It turns out that the actual likelihood at this point is:

$L(p_1=0.25,p_2=0.5,p_3=0.25|x_1=3,x_2=6,x_3=3)=$

$=\frac{12!}{3!6!3!}0.25^30.6^60.25^6=0.07050$

Now, let's assume I knew in advance that $p_1=p_3$. How would that change my result? It would not - I would still get the same parameter values $p_1=0.25,p_2=0.5,p_3=0.25$.

The twist comes now: let's assume I cannot observe balls that landed in $b_3$. If I know that 12 balls were thrown I am fine, since I can calculate $b_3=n-b_1-b_2=12-3-6=3$. but what happens if I don't know $n$?

I figure that in this case, I would need to estimate $x_3$ (or equivalently $n$) as well. However, if I use MLE, the results start looking weird. Intuitively, I would expect that if I observe $x_1=3,x_2=6$ and I know that $p_1=p_3$, then the MLE will probably be  $p_1=0.25,p_2=0.5,p_3=0.25,x_3=3$. However, it is clearly not the maximum, since for example:

$L(p_1=0.24,p_2=0.52,p_3=0.24|x_1=3,x_2=6,x_3=2)=$

$=\frac{11!}{3!6!2!}0.24^30.52^60.24^2=0.07273$

So from this it seems that $x_1=3,x_2=6,x_3=2$ is more likely than $x_1=3,x_2=6,x_3=3$ even if I know that $p_1=p_3$, which seems very counter-intuitive.

**My questions are whether my logic is sound, whether my intuition is misleading me and whether this is the correct way to estimate the parameters and missing data.**

**EDIT:**

For future reference, I found [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2239906) highly relevant paper, which addresses this exact problem. It also discusses the slight skew mentioned in whuber's answer.

Comment: The reason that $[3,6,2]$ has a higher probability than $[3,6,3]$ is because it is less data.

Comment: @jerad I think you are right, but I am not sure what this means. Does this mean it is incorrect to use MLE here? What would be the proper way of estimating $x_3$?

Comment: I can't say anything constructive about that. If you can't observe $x_3$ or $N$, and you have no prior knowledge that constrains the possibilities then all you're left with is making a random guess, which isn't that useful. In any case, if your data sets are rather small (as in your examples) then I'd suggest doing Bayesian inference to estimate $p$.

Comment: @jerad unfortunately my actual numbers are quite large. It seems to me that there should still be a way to fit $x_3$ without prior knowledge. The likelihood decreases as $x_3$ gets very large, and obviously it cannot be negative. BTW if $x_3=0$, there is even less data but the ML is still lower than $x_3=3$, so less data does not necessarily mean higher likelihood.

Comment: You don't seem to be working out the likelihood under the correct model. The likelihood that corresponds to the situation you describe near the end has no observation at all for $x_3$ and the known fact that $p_1=p_3$. If you work out some *other* likelihood, that fact that it's larger or smaller doesn't appear to be relevant - it wouldn't relate to the situation at hand.

Comment: @Glen_b I am not sure I understand. The value of $x_3$ is unknown (not necessarily zero), as are $p_1,p_2,p_3$. What I calculate is the probability of $x|p$, which is the likelihood.

Comment: If you're able to calculate the likelihood of $x_1 = 3$, $x_2=6$, $x_3=2$, *you're using the wrong likelihood*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One way to square your intuition with ML is to recognize that ML estimates are often biased.**  The ML estimate of $N$ looks like it's biased a little low.

There are only two parameters, $N$ and $p=p_1$, because $p_3=p_1=p$ and $p_2 = 1-p_1-p_3 = 1-2p$.  The log likelihood for observations $(a,b)$ is

$$\log(\Lambda) = \log\binom{N}{a,b,N-a-b} + (N-b)\log(p) + b\log(1-2p)$$

which for any $N$ is maximized at the unique zero of its derivative, $p = (N-b)/(2N)$. It is apparent, too, that as a function of $N$ this is concave downward. Thus to obtain the MLE for $N$ we can scan over $N=a+b, a+b+1, \ldots$ until finding a maximum.  (There are more efficient ways, but this works well enough.)  For example, with $(a,b)=(3,6)$, the maximum occurs for $\widehat{N}=11$ where $\hat{p} = 5/22$.

Here is a histogram of $10^5$ iid draws of this MLE from a Multinomial$(12; 1/4, 1/2, 1/4)$ distribution:

[image: Figure 1]

The shift to a peak at $\widehat{N}=11$ is clear.  For larger $N$ the shift still appears to be leftwards by only a small amount.  Here is a histogram from a simulation with a Multinomial$(120; 1/4, 1/2, 1/4)$ distribution:

[image: Figure 2]

The bias looks like a shift of $1$ or $2$ leftwards (the peak is at $119$ and the mean is $118.96$), but certainly there is not a proportional shift to $11/12 * 120 = 110$.

Although (because $N$ must be integral) some care should be used in applying standard ML results, the mathematical formulation of the likelihood makes sense for non-integral $N$ (via Gamma functions), so you're probably ok using the usual ML-based confidence intervals, etc.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! This phenomenon is quite interesting. In my specific application, using Gamma functions makes sense. So you are saying that MLE is reasonable for a large $N$? I am trying to use an EM-type algorithm (for MLE) by alternating between estimating $N$ and estimating $p_i$ (which are more complicated that presented above).

Comment: I don't see any reason why MLE is not reasonable for this problem.